# Nullable Foreign Key in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to allow a foreign key,which reference a primary key in another table , to be null-able . The problem is if I allow the foreign key to be null by ticking the option NULL in phpMyAdmin, it will not be able to create a foreign key constraint because the column of the two table are not the same.

I have a table **Taxi** which has a foreign key **Owner_ID** from the table **Owner**. However, I don't want it to be required, because sometimes you just don't know who the owner is.

Comment: If you're requiring null-able foreign keys - your schema is almost certainly dreadfully wrong.

Comment: @BenM edited, how do you suppose I do this

Comment: Create an `Unknown` owner with a fixed ID?

Comment: @BenM is that how people do it? set the foreign key to null sounds much more straight forward.

Comment: Foreign keys should never be null, otherwise you have orphaned data, which defeats the object of normalization...

Comment: @BenM but my Taxi table is a strong entity.